# AWS Athena query appending results to table?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have an Amazon Athena table that I created with the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 ( string1 string, string2 string)
LOCATION 's3://xyz/abc'
```

I then populated the table via

```
INSERT INTO table1 (string1, string2)
values ('1','2'),('3','4')...
```

This all worked just fine. However, when I query the table via

```
select count(*)
from table1
```

I get a number. If I run this query again, the count has gone up. Running it again, and the count goes up again. I think what is happening is that the results of the query (and maybe the query itself) are somehow being saved to the table. Where is the setting for this and how do I stop it from happening? I don't mind if a table stores the query and result information, just so long as it is not table1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that the `location` you specified for the table storage is the same as the configured [query result location](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying.html#query-results-specify-location).

This would cause the results of every `SELECT` to be stored in the same location, therefore 'appending' data to the table.

You should keep those two locations separate.

Comment: This makes sense. However, it seems that whenever I elect a non-empty folder location for my `CREATE TABLE... LOCATION`, any data within parquet files that are children of that aforementioned folder (either in a nested folder, or at that level) is automatically added as well. Is this normal behavior? Does any created table automatically inherent information/data from any nested parquet files? If so, how can I ensure I can create a totally empty table?

Comment: Yes, any objects in sub-folders are always included in the table data, too. When creating a table, the location should point to a Prefix that  _only_ contains data for that table. To ensure a totally empty table, give it a bucket and prefix that does not point to existing objects. On the other hand, to create a table with data that is already in Amazon S3, set the location to where the data already resides. See: [Table location in Amazon S3 - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-location-format.html)